# Is there a Content Delivery Network (CDN) that hosts Google Code Prettify?

Tags: cdn, prettify, typepad

Is there a [content delivery network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) (CDN) that is hosting [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)?

I am putting together a blog on [TypePad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypePad) and would like to take advantage of a CDN if possible.

Comment: + 1 Google doesn't seem to host prettify for some reason, odd: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/#jquery

Comment: @Kane I've made a suggestion that it be added: http://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-apis/issues/detail?id=393. Based on the lack of answers here I am guessing it's going to be a wait until Google adds it.

Comment: I wish they would, because: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96519/is-it-legal-to-use-the-content-delivery-network-cdn-which-belongs-to-stack-exch

Comment: We should all "heavily lobby Google to host this" as Jeff says.  Click the star icon next to Issue 393 on the link @ahsteele provided:  http://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-apis/issues/detail?id=393

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a CDN for prettify:

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/google/code-prettify@master/loader/run_prettify.js
```

Its use is explained on the official [code-prettify repository](https://github.com/google/code-prettify). You can use it with a skin, like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/google/code-prettify@master/loader/run_prettify.js?skin=desert"></script>
```

That way you don't have to worry about additional CSS files. For more details and a full list of URL configurations, check the [Getting Started](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/docs/getting_started.md) section.

---

As mentioned by Jan Šotola, the previous RawGit CDN was shut down.
Read more details on [migrating away from deprecated RawGit](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/js-code-prettifier/IFHev_kLm30).

Comment: RawGit CDN is shutting down. It is recommended to use jsDelivr CDN instead.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/js-code-prettifier/IFHev_kLm30

Answer (score 34):

Found it!

http://www.cdnjs.com/libraries/prettify

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/r298/run_prettify.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/r298/prettify.css" type="text/css">
```

Update: https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/issues/695 (see bottom of page)

Comment: Yes, but where is the .css file?

Comment: Not all the language files are listed comparing to the files hosted on Google Code. Is it just not showing? What happens when the requested language is not there on CloudeFare?

Comment: +1 I would have chosen @Peter Dietz answer for its simplicity. But your's works too http://jsfiddle.net/9LY48/3/ fwiw its a little hard to tell it was working until I added lang-css to the classname... Helps to read the docs I guess.

Comment: For rev 298 : r298/prettify.js did not work for me, r298/run_prettify.js did work.

Comment: The problem with this is that you cannot use URL configurations, like skin. Visit [the code-prettify repo](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) to get the latest CDN url.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you could use it directly from Google Code though.. ?
embeding
http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/prettify.js

Comment: This is not a good way though - it could change without notice.

Comment: Also it is served as is instead of gziped which a normal CDN should does.

Comment: Here's the CSS: http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/prettify.css

Answer (score 4):

**You can use Google Code Prettify directly.**

Read their [Google Code Prettify Readme](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) or [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/wiki/GettingStarted), and they tell you how to use them as the hosting provider.

```
<script
 src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then to use the prettyprint powers of Google Code Prettify, add `class="prettyprint"` to your code blocks, which should be in a `pre` or a `code`. Examples below:

```
<pre class="prettyprint">...</pre>
```

or

```
<code class="prettyprint">...</code>
```

Comment: It does work, but slows down my site because (1) does not always responds within a second and (2) most important, the Expire header is not correctly set in the future, so browser cache cannot do his job

Answer (score -2):

You could create an account on [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) and put all the JavaScript and CSS files in the public folder. This worked for me!